# Does the bold verb in the mentioned sentence require a third-person s?

Tags: subjunctives, third-person-singular

> According to that theory, knowledge does not require that the believer **possess/possesses** positive reason.

Answer (score 4):

While the subject "believer" would take a third-person singular verb conjugation in the present indicative (possesses), this is a [subjunctive](http://www.wordpower.ws/grammar/gramch09.html) construction, so it can take the infinitive form.

Not everyone uses the subjunctive in English. I would say "possess" here, but a lot of people might say "possesses."

So, in short, using "possesses" is certainly not required, but it also wouldn't necessarily be considered wrong.